# Can g(t) be integrated with respect to t? Been stuck on this one for a while

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Trying to work out the closed curve circulation of a velocity profile. The final integral that has been formed is:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}r^3g(t)dt$$

Can somebody help? Not sure whether g(t) can even be integrated?

Comment: There is no picture and you should use Latex for formatting your mathematical notation.

Comment: this is impossible to answer without knowing g.

Answer (score 1):

Use g(t) as its equivalent (derivative of velocity) and integrate using an abstract function unless the question is assuming g(t) is the constant function used on earth. I think using F = M*mg/r^2 = m*dv\dt and substituting g(t) into your function would be a plausible option as g(t) =~a(t). If it's a periodic function then you have the square root relation of T but I'd need more info to confirm. As you are integrating over 2pi I believe g is the relation of a periodic function (root relation), which can be explicitly solved for and plugged into the formula. A picture would certainly clarify! :)

Comment: how did you get any of that from his simple question?

Comment: Deduction and Newtonian physics?